# How to store and filter an array that contains 10k entries required for an autocomplete input client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, architecture, autocomplete

I have an array that has 10k entries of tags, the entries are not going to be rendered to the dom so I don't want solutions as `react-virtualized`, `infinite scroll`, etc..

The sole purpose of the array to be used by an autocomplete input to search, filter and return suggested tags from the array.

My questions are:

1. I don't want to overwhelm my backend server by continuously querying what the user has typed, so what are the available options and solutions to be able to store the array client side?
2. If it is allowed to just store the array in a variable,

- Should it be stored in redux, state, ref, or imported from a file that exports this Array?
- Do re-renders would have a negative impact due to the Array size
- Would it affect performance?
- Would it increase application bundle size?

3. What would be the options to query, search and filter through the Array when user types inside the autocomplete input, as I don't know whether `search()` and `findIndex()` to go through 10k entry is efficient or not?

Comment: We can only tell you whether to store in redux, ref, state once we see how you use it. Is it in multiple places or just in one place. Yes, it would impact re-renders but can be managed by efficiently writing it. Application bundle size wont be increased until you save it in a file and export. If you make API call once and get all the list and save it in redux/state/ref, its not related to bundle size. You have to find out a better search algorithm to do efficient searching. May be try out different searching algorithms that we have

Comment: @G_S Thanks for the reply, I will only use the autocomplete in a single component so it is just in one place. should the array be in a separate file as Array.js and imported by the component? should it be stored inside a `ref` to avoid re-rendering performance issues? is it better to API call the file once and store it rather than already storing it client side? sorry I am asking a lot as I don't have the enough information to begin with.

Comment: I would suggest using a API call and get data when there are chances that the data changes in BE. If it is a fixed list ( never changing or rarely changing), we can think of adding it to the javascript code and refer wherever you need. As to bundle size, try building the production binaries and check difference in bundle size. ( it depends on data that you load, number of properties it has etc etc).

Comment: If you are using it as an import, you would anyhow use a variable to hold the data. when you are typing you need to re-render the list, which means it needs to be updated regularly. This updated list can be saved in state variable. ( Try out debouncing effect also if needed or start searching the list only after user types in 3 characters or so). When saving as a file and exporting it whereever needed, consider using code splitting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry so much about the speed of query, as it will be run per user input, plus the search complexity most likely will be O(N) search in 10k items, it should be instantaneous, but of course there are benchmarks which array functions faster than the other, go with traditional `for` loop if you really looking for the faster speed.

For re-renders, it will only re-render when user type something on the autocomplete, so other than typing on autocomplete, it shouldn't re-render the list because user is not on focus event on the autocomplete input.

On where would you store this array it completely depends on who will use this array, is it by many components? can we alter the data? will it just 10k items without the ability to add/remove/edit the item?

If you store it in frontend, there's no way the bundle size is not increasing. But maybe you can utilize code splitting, if the autocomplete only shows on certain page, so it will only loads the JS file when user navigate there

Comment: The array will be used inside only one place, only search no add, delete or update.
For sure bundle size would increase but is the size difference noticeable?

Comment: Put the array in a file and import it, that should be sufficient. About size, it is noticable. even if the array just contains numbers from 1...10000. it will be around 49kb~ txt file. not sure how much web server can compress, but that's the base size.